# ¿Cómo validar 2 file input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Me gustaría saber de que manera puedo comparar que dos input file tiene cargado archivos y habilitar un botón al momento que detecte que los 2 ya cargaron información.

> **NOTA:** Si uno de los inputs no tiene información el botón se deshabilita, solo de habilita siempre y cuando los 2 tengan información (solo tengo este código y funciona solo en un botón).

Este es el código que tengo:

```
$(function() {
    $('#Field1').change(function(){
        $('#btn').prop("disabled", this.files.length == 0);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crea un método que realice la validación en lugar del *function* anónimo que creas, y para cada input verificas que tenga algún valor con **`.val()`** si ambos tienen valor entonces cambias la propiedad al botón.

```js
function validar() {
    // Aqui verificamos que ambos tengan valor
    $("#btnEnviar").prop("disabled", (!$("#Field1").val() || !$("#Field2").val()));
}
// En el evento change le envías el método al que accederá una vez cambiado el valor (El change debe hacerse para cada input en este caso)
$("#Field1").change(validar);
$("#Field2").change(validar);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="Field1" />
<input type="file" id="Field2" />

<button id='btnEnviar' disabled="disabled">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: Gracias , amigos posiblemente siga preguntado por este medio otras dudas que me surgen

Answer (score 1):

Puedes evaluar el estado de los botones apoyándote de un booleano para cada `input`, aquí indico que si el valor del `input` tiene valor, su estado va a cambiar a `true`. Luego hay una condicional donde digo que si ambos booleanos son `true`, habilito el botón, de lo contrario permanece deshabilitado. Ejemplo:

```js
$(function() {
  var file1 = false;
  var file2 = false;

  $('#Field1').change(function() {
    // si esto cumple, "file1" es true, de lo contrario es false.
    file1 = this.files.length > 0;
    verificarInputs();
  });

  $('#Field2').change(function() {
    // si esto cumple, "file2" es true, de lo contrario es false.
    file2 = this.files.length > 0;
    verificarInputs();
  });

  function verificarInputs() {
    // Si "file1" y "file2" son true, habilito el botón, de lo contrario permanece deshabilitado.
    if (file1 && file2) {
      $('#btn').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('#btn').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="file" id="Field1"><br>
<input type="file" id="Field2"><br>
<br>
<button id='btn' disabled>Enviar</button>
```